# How to encode unicode strings to utf-8 in a list with both unicode and float values using python

Tags: python

I have a list with both unicode and float values:

```
list=[u'name',523]
```

I want to convert only the string to utf-8 in the list. How can i do that using python?

```
[x.encode('utf-8') for x in items]
```

I have the used the code snippet above to encode but i am getting the following error:

```
Float values cannot be enoded
```

Comment: 32 or 64 bit float ? Maybe 128 bits. Use `try - except`, sometime short ways waste a lot time and check every item `type` before converting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do:

```
[x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in items]
```

Comment: You put the ternary in the front when you want to include an `else` clause too. If you just want the `if` without the `else` you have to put it in the back (after the `for`).

Comment: i am not sure why this difference exists but my guess is that an `if` statement alone "operates" on the constructor (__for x in items__) and populates it with those `x` that fulfill the `if` condition. On the other hand, an `if-else` statement influences which operation is performed on the `x` so the logic is not actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

like so:

```
orig_list = [u'name', 523]
mod_list = [x.encode('utf-8') if type(x) == str else x for x in orig_list]

print(mod_list)  # prints: [b'name', 523]
```

Comment: iam getting output like this ['u', "'", 'n', 'a',' m', 'e' "'"] but i want like['name',523]

Comment: it works perfectly for me. What python version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

For python3, unicode objects are type `str`, so you want

```
[x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in items]
```

In python2, it's `unicode`,

```
[x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, unicode) else x for x in items]
```

With the `future` library you can do both.

```
[x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, future.text_type) else x for x in items]
```

Answer (score -1):

For python2:
`[x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, basestring) else x for x in items]`

For python3:
`[x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in items]`

Or use `six`:
`[x.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, six.string_types) else x for x in items]`

Comment: I am getting syntax errror at isinstance.

Comment: I made the same mistake :P You have to put the ternary operation in front of the loop

Comment: Thanks guys. Fixed it.